# GSON: Nested class extension

Tags: java, gson

Hello I got the following JSON data which is obtained via search call

Let this be called **Lite**

```
{
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/8MlZPgAACAAJ",
 "id": "8MlZPgAACAAJ",
  "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Harry Potter Textbook Box Set",
    "authors": [
      "J. K. Rowling"
    ],
    "publisher": "Scholastic",
    "publishedDate": "2001-11-01",

  }
}
```

In the data there is a selfLink element that takes you to more details.

Which can look like this. As you can see there is more elements.

Let this be called **Fat**

```
{
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/8MlZPgAACAAJ",
  "id": "8MlZPgAACAAJ",
  "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Harry Potter Textbook Box Set",
    "authors": [
      "J. K. Rowling"
    ],
    "publisher": "Scholastic",
    "publishedDate": "2001-11-01",
    "description": "Presents facsimile editions of two books from the world of Harry Potter--the text for Hogwarts' Care of Magical Creatures class and a book on the origins and development of the wizarding game of Quidditch.",
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
      "Juvenile Fiction / Fantasy & Magic"
    ],
    "language": "en",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8MlZPgAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8MlZPgAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Harry_Potter_Textbook_Box_Set.html?hl=&id=8MlZPgAACAAJ"
  }
}
```

This class models lite

```
        public class Lite{
            @SerializedName("selfLink")
            private String mSelfLink;

            @SerializedName("volumeInfo")
            private VolInfo mVolInfo;

        public static class VolInfo {
            @SerializedName("title")
            private String mTitle;

            @SerializedName("publishedDate")
            private String mPublishedDate;

            @SerializedName("authors")
            private String[] mAuthors;

            @SerializedName("publishedDate")
            private String mPublishedDate;
            }
}
```

And then to model Fat

```
public class Fat extends Lite{

@SerialisedName("id")
private String mId;

  @SerializedName("volumeInfo")
  private VolInfo mVolInfo;


 public static class VolInfo extends Lite.VolInfo {
       // The other elements that is in the fat call
}

}
```

But the problem is I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  declares multiple JSON fields
>   named volumeInfo

So is it possible to extend inner class in GSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Fat class is declaring a second "volumeInfo". It should just use the superclasses field instead of declaring a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from you **Fat** model class:

```
  @SerializedName("volumeInfo")
  private VolInfo mVolInfo;
```

You cannot have multiple attributes with the same names. In your case the `volumeInfo` attribute is in the **Fat** class and **Lite** class

If you want to access the **Lite** attributes from your **Fat** class declare the Lite attributes with a `public` modifier. Simply change the `private` to `public` before variables:

```
private VolInfo mVolInfo;
```

to

```
public VolInfo mVolInfo;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. How would I access the nested VolInfo class in Fat class so get access to the fields because all I can do now is access the super class but not the ones specific to fat

Comment: @johncarter I edited my answer, you can change the private variables to public in the Lite class. Only then you can access those variables from your Fat class

Comment: Hi, I can access lite already, but I want to access the fat attributes.

Comment: I dont understand, from where are you trying to access the fat attributes

Comment: The Fat JSON contains more attributes then the light version. When I make a network call to get the detail (fat), I deserialise using the Fat model which inherits from lite so that I can access the lite attributes as you mentioned plus the attributes specific to fat only. Lite cannot see these attributes declared in fat